# Asus Zenbook UX433FA audio doesn’t work

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, asus

I am pretty new to linux and dual booting, but I wanted to do dual boot on my Asus Zenbook because Windows seems too slow for me and im into development etc.

I succesfully dual-booted my laptop but cant make audio to work. I tried both Ubuntu 18.04 and 19.04. I even tried to change kernel version because I saw some answers on stackoverflow but that did not work.

Is here anybody that dealt with similar problems and succesfully managed to solve it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Open terminal.
2. Type `alsamixer` and take all of the controls to max level.
3. Press <kbd>Esc</kbd> key, and close terminal with `exit`.
4. Check whether sound works.

Comment: Nope, I unmuted everything and put 100 value everywhere. It still doesn’t reproduce any sound.